# JTextPane should keeps position at update

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtextarea, jtextpane

I have a long text in a textPane (inside a scrollPane) that updates automatically. After update the pane scrolls to the top of the textPane. How can i deactivate the "top-scroll" (like the textArea does). I can not use a textArea because I style the text in pane with HTML. I can't do this style with a textArea, right? :(

```
public void create(){
    ...
    scrollpane.setViewportView(textPane);
    textPane.setEditable(false);
    textPane.setContentType("text/html");
    ...
}

public void update(String text){
   textPane.setText(text);
}
```

Thanks for help!

SOLUTION:

```
public void update(final String iv_outputText) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            ((DefaultCaret) textPane.getCaret())
                    .setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
            textPane.setText(iv_outputText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Set the caret position to the last position within the text pane.

Comment: A [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem would also be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((DefaultCaret)textPane.getCaret()).setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE)
```

You can try update policy for the caret

Comment: Thanks for help but this did not solve my problem :(

Comment: You can store visible rectangle and scroll back after the setText()

Comment: Now it Works!!! I have combined the response of mbw of these. I have the code posted above

Answer (score 0):

I think I've done something similar to what you're looking for.  Take a look at my answer to this question here:

[Keep JScrollPane as same length java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391798/keep-jscrollpane-as-same-length-java/25410212#25410212)